# Match a substring that might contain reserved characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm having some issues with matching one string to another if the string I'm testing for contains regex characters.

Background: I'm working on a script that migrates news articles from 2 legacy systems into one. In some cases, these stories are duplicated within the systems, so I'm running a script to check stored data an archive file (in html form) to see if the title of the current story matches anything in the archive.

```
#...(for each line) 
line.match(title) then
    return true
end
```

This generally works, except when I have a regex character in the title, for example:

```
<span class="title">$8.9 Million Grant for UC Center Focused on Occupational Safety and Health</span>
```

doesn't match

```
$8.9 Million Grant for UC Center Focused on Occupational Safety and Health
```

Here's some example output from irb to demonstrate

```
2.3.0 :012 > str = '<span class="title">$8.9 Million Grant for UC Center Focused on Occupational Safety and Health</span>'
2.3.0 :020 > str.match("$8.9 Million Grant for UC Center Focused on Occupational Safety and Health")
 => nil 
2.3.0 :021 > str.match("\\$8.9 Million Grant for UC Center Focused on Occupational Safety and Health")
 => #<MatchData "$8.9 Million Grant for UC Center Focused on Occupational Safety and Health"> 
2.3.0 :022 > str.match("8.9 Million Grant for UC Center Focused on Occupational Safety and Health")
 => #<MatchData "8.9 Million Grant for UC Center Focused on Occupational Safety and Health"> 
2.3.0 :023 >
```

So I'm pretty sure the `$` is the issue, and that the issue stems from it being a recursive regex character.

Ruby isn't my daily language, and I'm having some trouble figuring out where to look to see if there either a ruby method to do the match without relying on regex, or to treat the pattern literally, or to automatically escape potential regex special characters. Help is appreciated.

Comment: You accepted the first answer offered, after only 15 minutes??

Comment: It worked, and it was concise.

Comment: There are several reasons for waiting awhile (at least a couple of hours, say) before selecting an answer. Firstly, an early selection may discourage other answers. In this case what if @philomony did not offer an answer (and no one else gave that answer)? Secondly, it short-circuits those still preparing answers. Thirdly, the selected answer is sometimes wrong and you don't want to discourage members from checking it. Moreover, there is no reason I am aware of to select an answer so quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.match(Regexp.new(Regexp.escape("$8.9 Million ...")))
=> #<MatchData "$8.9 Million Grant for UC Center Focused...
```

Comment: Thanks. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the MatchData (such as where in the string the target text occurs), a much simpler solution would be to use [`String#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
str.include?("$8.9 Million")
# => true
```

If you *do* need the location the match occurs, using [`String#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-index) is still simpler:

```
str.index("$8.9 Million")
# => 20
```

Comment: Was about to suggest the same once I figured out the objective.